# Navigation bar items are invisible

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

Xcode 10, Swift 5

I'm trying to create a button on the navigation bar but I can't get it to actually be displayed. The setup of my project is:

1. ViewController1 (VC1, yellow): "Click" button that starts segue to
2. NavigationController (NC): Segue to
3. ViewController2 (VC2, red): "Next" button that loads
4. ViewController3 (VC3, green)

Embedding VC2 in a `UINavigationController` and connecting it to VC3 with a segue automatically creates a "Back" button in VC3.

[image]

How do I make my "Button" on the right in the `UINavigationBar` in VC3 become visible - using only the Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I made was to add a `UINavigationBar`, which was added behind the existing `UINavigationBar` and because of this all of its items were invisible!

A `UINavigationBar` that was automatically added by a `UINavigationController` doesn't show up in the hierarchy! There'll be one if there's a "back" button, so in this case add a `UINavigationItem` instead. This creates a `Title` item.

Drag the new item you want to add over the left or right side of the `UINavigationBar` and there'll be a blue square, indicating where you can drop it. This item can be a `UIBarButtonItem` (which can be linked up like a button), a `UIButton` (which automatically also creates a `UIBarButtonItem`),... or even a `UIView`. Dropping an item adds it to the hierarchy and if it's the very first one, two new children are also going to be added to the `Title`:

1. Left Bar Button Items
2. Right Bar Button Items

[image]

Important: Adding something to the left "drop zone" overwrites the "back" button, which means that you're going to have to deal with going back to the previous screen yourself. This is easily accomplished by creating an "onClick" action for this item (ctrl+drag to the .swift file) and then calling:

`navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

[image]

Comment: so, if you just find the decision pls mark your answer as resolved :)

Comment: You have to wait 2 days before you can accept your own answer. ;)